# Datagrams are being sent, but not being received + additional questions

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio

I'm very new to network programming.

I've written the below exe which I've then executed on two separate machines on my local network. The idea is that it spawns a thread to listen to and react to datagrams on a specific port and then in the main thread it allows the user to send data.

Via Wireshark, I can see the datagrams being sent from the other machine, hitting this machine on the correct port, however my exe is not reacting to it. I cannot see what part of my async receive is incorrect.

Also in Wireshark I can see the send messages being sent to the correct machines IP on the correct port, again, on the other machine the .exe doesn't appear to receive the messages.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class UDPConnector
{
public:
    UDPConnector(asio::io_service& io_service)
    : m_socket(io_service)
    {
        auto endpoint = asio::ip::udp::endpoint(asio::ip::udp::v4(),34724);
        m_socket.open(endpoint.protocol());
        m_socket.bind(endpoint);

        StartReceiving();
    }

protected:

    void StartReceiving()
    {
        m_socket.async_receive_from(asio::buffer(m_receiveBuffer), m_remoteEndpoint,
                                    std::bind(&UDPConnector::HandleReceive, this,
                                              std::placeholders::_1,
                                              std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void HandleReceive(const asio::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes)
    {
        if(!error)
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            for(auto c : m_receiveBuffer)
                ss << c;
            std::cout << "received: " << ss.str() << std::endl;

            /* listen for the next post */
            StartReceiving();
        }
        else if(error == asio::error::message_size)
        {
            std::cout << "Message was larger than receive buffer" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    asio::ip::udp::socket m_socket;
    asio::ip::udp::endpoint m_remoteEndpoint;
    std::vector<char> m_receiveBuffer;
};

asio::io_service io_serviceListen;

void Listen()
{
    UDPConnector udpServer(io_serviceListen);
    io_serviceListen.run();
}

int main()
{
    std::thread listenThread(Listen);

    asio::io_service io_serviceSend;
    asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver(io_serviceSend);

    std::string dest;
    std::cout << "dest: ";
    std::cin >> dest;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << "Broadcast something: " << std::endl;
        std::string msg;
        std::cin >> msg;

        if(msg == "exit")
            break;

        asio::ip::udp::resolver::query query(asio::ip::udp::v4(), dest, "34724");
        asio::ip::udp::endpoint receiverEndpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
        asio::ip::udp::socket socket(io_serviceSend);
        socket.open(asio::ip::udp::v4());
        socket.send_to(asio::buffer(msg), receiverEndpoint);
    }

    io_serviceListen.stop();
    listenThread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I also have another off-hand question. I noticed in wireshark that despite sending to a specific port, the source port is some random number. Why is this, I thought that it would go through the same port.

### EDIT

So I've worked out that I am receiving the packets in the .exe, however there is something wrong. In the `HandleReceive` member, I've found that there is an asio::error_code `234` (`More data is available`) and that the `bytes` parameter is 0.

I can't find anything in the asio reference material that specifies how and when the different errors are received. In Wireshark, I can see that the data is in the packet that the .exe is receiving.

Comment: Plenty of things to look for probably . Get a look at this .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257367/boost-udp-asynchronous-client-receiving-its-own-datagram

Comment: The source port has no relationship with the target port. It is usually allocated fairly randomly by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I found out my answer in the asio documentation. Turns out that `asio::buffer` doesn't exactly behave like I thought. It needs to be provided with a contiguous array of memory (which `std::vector` provides) however it needs to have a set size for it to actually make use of.

ASIO won't resize the `std::vector` to fill with the contents of the packet. It just uses the `.size()` of the vector, in this case 0. The error was to say that there was still more data available, because it hadn't put any into the provided buffer (because it was 0 length).

So changing the `UDPConnector` constructor to:

```
UDPConnector(asio::io_service& io_service)
: m_socket(io_service), m_receiveBuffer(128)
```

solves the immediate problem.